# Google Analytics - Tracking Impressions using a User ID

Tags: google-analytics

Can I use a User ID to collect information per User ID regarding impressions of display ads in referral sites?  Can I have information telling me that a certain User ID was exposed to a particular Display Ad in a specific site identified by its name and path?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google Analytics does not report impressions at all (it reports clicks), unless your ads are displayed via some linked Google product (Adwords/Doubleclick).

Tying user ids to ad impressions would allow you to profile users and track their way as they travel through the internet. This would blatantly illegal in many legislations. It would also be rather challenging technology-wise, since there is no easy way to tie an ad impression to an existing client id.

So in short, no.